# IIS Virtual Folders Permissions per User Account

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, permissions, virtual-directory

I have a website with the below structure for saving product images:

```
~/fileserver/{user_id}/{file_id}.{file_extension}
```

I want to restrict access to each `{user_id}` folder and let only the specific user to retrieve that image. How this can be done? Do I have to set something in IIS?

Answer (score 1):

[Write an HttpModule](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020417.htm) that checks the request path. If the path contains `fileserver/{user_id}`, and `user_id` is a valid user, then check to see if `user_id` is authenticated.

[Many tutorials on how to do this are available](http://google.com/search?q=asp.net+http+module).